# Как в value вставить переменную JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div class="demo">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hd-1" class="hide"/>
            <label for="hd-1"><h2>Текст<div class="gradient-progressbar"><progress max="708" value="20" id="progress"></progress></div></h2></label>    
            <div>
                <b>Количество страниц</b>: <span id="allPages1"></span> <br>
                <b>Прочитано</b>: <span id="pages1"></span>     
            </div>
</div>
```

И

```
  </body>


  <script>
    var allPages1 = 708; 
    var pages1 = 262; 


    document.getElementById("allPages1").innerHTML = allPages1; 
    document.getElementById("pages1").innerHTML = pages1;   
  </script>
```

Как в `value` прогресса добавить переменную?

Comment: Вы же уже добавили,  document.getElementById("pages1").innerHTML = pages1; Перефразируйте вопрос, уподробнитесь слегонца.

Comment: так а как её в progress теперь добавить? <progress max="708" value="pages1".... не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_progress_value.asp

```js
var allPages1 = 708; 
var pages1 = 262; 


document.getElementById("allPages1").innerHTML = allPages1; 
document.getElementById("pages1").innerHTML = pages1; 

document.getElementById('progress').value = pages1;
```

```html
    <div class="demo">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hd-1" class="hide"/>
            <label for="hd-1"><h2>Текст<div class="gradient-progressbar"><progress max="708" value="20" id="progress"></progress></div></h2></label>    
            <div>
                <b>Количество страниц</b>: <span id="allPages1"></span> <br>
                <b>Прочитано</b>: <span id="pages1"></span>     
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!